# Is it possible to attach a copy of a mail to this mail in Mandrill?

Tags: php, html, json, pdf, mandrill

I'm receiving some data in the form of either a .json or a php data file.
Form this data I'm generating an email. So every mail looks different and has a different amount of data.

I would like to parse the same data into a pdf file that I can attach to this mail. 
So the email would have an attachment, that is a "copy" of the emails content.

This mail is send via Mandrill, and I'm using the usual Handlebar logik to parse the data form the .json/pho data file.

Is there any way I can achieve this, without external steps, like parsing and creating a pdf on a server?